# Which is the best method to check the network reachability in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, reachability

I'm new to objective c. I found a lot of method for checking the internet connectivity like reachability test, using AF Networking etc.Which is the best method?Any help?

Comment: you can use reachability.

Comment: Download Reachability class 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always prefer to use Reachability https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability like below. Description on GitHub is so clear for why you should use it -> "This is a drop-in replacement for Apple's Reachability class. It is ARC-compatible, and it uses the new GCD methods to notify of network interface changes".

```
Reachability *internetReachableFoo = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

// Internet is reachable
internetReachableFoo.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
{
    // Update the UI on the main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        //do something
        NSLog(@"REACHABLE!");

        } error:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
            NSLog(@"Error:%@ ", [error localizedDescription]);
        }];
    });
};

// Internet is not reachable
internetReachableFoo.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
{
    // Update the UI on the main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        //do something
        NSLog(@"UNREACHABLE!");

        });
};

[internetReachableFoo startNotifier];
```

goodluck :)